# Decomposition of a separating curve

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider a genus 2 surface. Its fundamental group can be expressed by
$$
\pi_1(S_2)=\langle\alpha_1,\beta_1,\alpha_2,\beta_2\:||[\alpha_1,\beta_1][\alpha_2,\beta_2] \rangle.
$$
I would like to know how to express the curve $\gamma$ as product of those generators when it is the separating curve that "separates one torus form the other": with "curve $\gamma$" I mean [the pink one in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwkqU.png).

Answer (score 3):

A genus 2 surface can be visualized in terms of an octagon with boundaries identified as in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9ROb.jpg) (this is a generalization of the usual way of seeing a torus as $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$: analogously, a genus $n$ surface can be viewed as a $4n$-gon with appropriate boundary identifications).

The curve in question becomes the [pink curve in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAunv.png), thus leading to (using *your* notation):

$$\gamma=[\alpha_1,\beta_1]=[\alpha_2,\beta_2]^{-1}$$

Edit: images taken from [How to construct a genus 2 surface from 8-gon?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479371/how-to-construct-a-genus-2-surface-from-8-gon).

Comment: That was a very nice explanation, thanks a lot!